# Youtube web app not working in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: youtube, webapps

I just installed Youtube web app in Ubuntu using this command,

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-youtube
```

but I cannot make it working or I do not find any Youtube icon on the dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the webapps feature and added it'd PPA before that?

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview`

Try that and then logout and back in to see if it works!

Comment: Problem may be a re login!

Comment: How do you mean? As in re-login is causing the problem or you can't re-login?

Comment: After installing Youtube web app I did not re login, may be that is the cause, but all other web apps like Gmail, Last.fm are working, why?

Comment: So have you re-logged at all since you've installed the Youtube lens? Also did you install Gmail, LastFM and other lenses at the same time as the youtube one or at an earlier date?

Comment: I was just re login and still only youtube web app is not working!

Comment: Hmm sorry I'm not of much help anymore so, I'm on Linux Mint can't test to see if it works myself.

Comment: Linux Mint is cool, I installed it on our family computer!

Comment: Updated to 13.04 and all web apps are working without any problems.